# How to increase the timeout period of a web service request in netsuite

Tags: session, netsuite

I want to increase the 'session timeout', which currently is set to 20 minutes. How can I increase or decrease it by one hour, or in other terms, 60 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to accomplish what you need, as we ran into the same issue when doing our NetSuite integration.

1. You can make a dummy search event every couple of min.  We searched for a bogus transaction that we knew would never be created, and limited to a date in the distant past and only that date.  That way the search would return very quickly with zero results.
2. Implement SingleSignOn.  This is the preferred method.  Once you initiate the single sign on, if the session has timed out on you previously you can quickly make a new session using tokens and do not need to ask the user for their username/password again.
3. We had a service that needed consumed at two different points in the application that did not know about each other.  So the way we got around this but still using one service was saving the cookies from the service in a shared location.  Then when the service is needed by one of the application they would recreate the service from the cookies.  If the service had timed out we would recreate the service and update the cookies.  This method became outdated once we implimented SingleSignOn, as then we could just create the service from the tokens as needed, and the tokens were stored in a shared location.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way that I know of in NetSuite, you could though use a browser plugin to refresh the page or click the home button every 19 mins. Would work if for example the person is AFK.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change the web service request timeout period (for sync operations it lasts approx 15 min, then the operation gets terminated on the server side). The general practice for long running operations that takes more than 15 mins is to use async requests.